# how to set default language in prestashop as french

Tags: php, task-parallel-library, prestashop

how to set default language in prestashop as french

Comment: the question is not programming related but you can find what you are looking for here http://www.prestashop.com/wiki/Languages_and_translations/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party product and should be addressed by their support

Answer (score 8):

on the Tools -> Languages tab in admin, at the bottom there is the option for choosing the default language...

just note that when a new user comes to your eshop and he has browser in english, then prestashop will automatically give him english language too (if its available in your shop)
the order for choosing users language is

1. cookie
2. browser language
3. default shop language

Answer (score 1):

in PrestaShop 1.5 you can set the default language in your "My Preferences" in the back office. You can enable which languages you want available in Localization>> Languages

Answer (score 1):

in presta 1.6.0 you can find this setting in the admin panel:

Localization-> Localization-> Default Language